# Vershik's conjecture about generic quadratic algebras

Tags: reference-request, ra.rings-and-algebras, homological-algebra

Is it still unknown whether *very general* (lying in a countable intersection of some Zariski opens in corresponding Grassmannian) quadratic algebras $R$ with $\operatorname{dim} R_2 < \frac{3}{4}(\operatorname{dim} R_1)^2$ are finite-dimensional?